# Sitecore User Group Belarus - February 17, 2017

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

The SUG Belarus organizers welcome you to Fourth Sitecore User Group event (Belarus ) that will take place February 17th at 19:00 (UTC 16:00) at Balki Project Tower (пр-т Дзержинского, 57)

https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-Belarus/events/237215879/

#### Agenda:

1st speaker: **Dmytro Shevchenko** - Senior Solutions Developer at Hedgehog Development, Sitecore MVP and Stackoverflow Guru.

“*Sitecore xDB In-Depth: Contacts, Sessions and Clusters*”

Summary: The APIs, infrastructure and data flows of Sitecore xDB are quite complex. Dmytro will explain the reasons behind this complexity, and show the proper ways of using xDB in a multi-cluster environment.

2nd speaker: **Georgi Bilyukov** - Senior Solutions Developer at Hedgehog Development, Sitecore MVP.

“*Continuous Integration and Continuous Delivery with Hedgehog Tool Suite*”

Summary: The main focus of the presentation are the Hedgehog's products TDS and RAZL and how to use them to set up a Continuous Integration and Delivery process. Georgi will cover the basic functionality of the products, as well as some advanced techniques.

3rd speaker: **Vladimir Zaverugo** - Lead Software Engineer at EPAM Systems

“*An introduction to working with Sitecore Experience Accelerator (SXA)*”

Summary: Released with last Sitecore version, Sitecore Experience Accelerator is a reusable set of  templated UX layouts and components designed to increase website implementation speed. Vladimir will share his experience with SXA and welcomes you to discuss it’s features.

Meetup will include time for discussions, networking and Q&A sessions.

Stay tuned for Agenda updates.

Comment: Please include UTC start and end time.

Comment: Event created. Will start showing in 6 days from now.